# Put label next to the input

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I have a simple case. I want two things.

1. Put label next to the input.
2. Some sort of validation, only digit number for the text box.

The corresponding [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/GCtPE/) is here.

Now the input is below the label.
My code:

```
<div id="generatePinsDialog" title="Generate New PINs">
<label style="display: inline-block; width: 400px;">
    How many?</label>
<input id="newInmateCount" type="text" size="25" value="Enter the number!" />
<br />
<select>
    <option value="sameAsID">Same as ID</option>
    <option value="appendID">AppendID</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice that you want that. But what have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: I tried display: inline-block, why it is not working?

Comment: Try using table>tr>td in your html OR float:left/right with divs OR a CSS grid. There are many many ways to solve this. try some, and if you still need help, come back and ask

Comment: Remove the `inline-block` from your label and add the `for` attribute: `<label for="newInmateCount" ...`

Comment: @Love `inline-block` *is* working, your element is 400px wide, which is pushing the input element to the right (causing it to wrap to the new line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the "inline-block" from your label and add the `for` attribute like so:

```
<label for="newInmateCount" style="width: 400px;">How many?</label>
```

As for the input, do this for numeric only:

```
$("#newInmateCount").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) return true; // for backspace and delete
    if (e.which < 48 || (e.which > 57 && e.which < 96) || e.which > 105) return false;
});
```

## See your jsFiddle Updated

Comment: Did you miss a double quote?

Answer (score 3):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCtPE/25/

```
label, input { display: inline-block; }
```

For verification you will have to use javascript since HTML5 isn't fully supported by all browsers. [HTML5 is pretty cool though.](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)

Comment: For numbers, you should probably be using `<input type="number" />`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `display: inline-block`. That is causing the input filed to go to new line.

You this js function to validate just digits, call it `onkeypress` event of the input field or bind it with `onkeydown` event

```
function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode( key );
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();   
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GCtPE/22/)

Comment: @Love Yes. it working at my end. The alphabets and other chars do not get entered, just the number get entered in the field.

Comment: @twodays Does the normal numeric keys work? the one above the qwert.

Answer (score 0):

to put the label next to the input, change `display:inline-block;` to `display:inline`, or decrease the `width:400px` to a lower value until you acheive the positioning you want. for validation you need to do some reading on **regular expressions**

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GCtPE/11/)
The input was so far to the right because you set the width of the label to 400px, I just removed that and it looks fine now. Also added some quick validation, you'd obviously have to run the validation when the form is submitted.

```
<div id="generatePinsDialog" title="Generate New PINs">
    <label style="display: inline-block;">
        How many?</label>
    <input id="newInmateCount" type="text" size="25" value="Enter the number!" />
    <br />
    <select>
        <option value="sameAsID">Same as ID</option>
        <option value="appendID">AppendID</option>
    </select>
 </div>​
```

And the JS is below:

```
if($('#newInmateCount').val() != "") {
    var value = $('#newInmateCount').val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    if(!intRegex.test(value)) {
        errors += "Field must be numeric.<br/>";
        success = false;
    }
} else {
    errors += "Field is blank.</br />";
    success = false;
}​
```

Comment: The default width is already auto so `width: auto;` can be removed from the label.

Answer (score 0):

On-submit validation is pretty easy with jQuery.  Here's an [example](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number).  If you want to keep it from ever having something other than numbers in it, you can go with an onchange or onkeyup event and simply strip the numbers from the input.

For the positioning, try inline instead of inline-block.